# Count the number of keys

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to count the number of keys in a node on the firebase cloud functions.

I have this db structure:

```
-- groups
     -- groupID
          -- information
          -- members
```

I trigger an event when a member is removed from the group.

```
exports.onDeleteMember = functions.database
    .ref('/groups/{groupId}/members')
    .onDelete(event => {
        console.log(event.ref.numChildren);
    })
```

But how can I count the remaining members in that particular group on the most efficient way? I thought to do a event.ref.numChilderen, but that doesn't work because I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'numChildren' of undefined`.

What I want is to delete the whole group when there are no members in the group anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. from the `event`, you need to get the `ref` from `event.data.ref`, not event.ref
   See:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#data
2. numChildren is a function, not a property, so you would call `console.log(event.data.ref.numChildren())`
3. Firebase will automatically delete a node with no children. So it would be impossible to have your Firebase data with Groups->GroupID->(no children). Firebase would have removed GroupID automatically.

You could check if the numChildren is 1, and if it is, remove the information node from the snapshot. Something like this:

```
exports.onDeleteMember = functions.database
    .ref('/groups/{groupId}/members')
    .onDelete(event => {
        // get the parent ref /groups/groupId children count
        if (event.data.ref.parent.numChildren() == 1) {
          // only 'information' left
          event.data.ref.parent.child('information').remove()
        }
    })
```

Comment: My bad, the groupID key contains another child named information. So it is not removed automatically.

Comment: updated my answer to account for the information object